# Entity Framework 6 can't work with large data

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, large-data

I'm having a trouble about working large data with entity framework 6. When I try to get data from database it gives timeout error. I'm just including 2 extra tables to my query. I mean I'm joining 3 tables and one of them is empty for now. (ORDERS, ORDER_DETAILS, PEOPLE)

ORDERS table has 385K records and PEOPLE has 400K of records. I'm also not getting all records. I'm taking just 25 records for one page. (I'm using paging.)

Here is my sample code. After 15 seconds it gives timeout error and when I get the tsql query from Sql Profiler it works but that takes 37 seconds.

```
// skipCount is integer and it changes with page number.
// pageSize is fixed integer number which is 25.
// I also set timeout about 180 seconds
var list = _uow.Repository<ORDERS>()
        .Query(x => x.ACTIVE == true)
        .Include(x => x.ORDER_DETAILS)
        .Include(x => x.PEOPLE)
        .OrderBy(sorting)
        .Skip(skipCount)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList();
```

Also if I use LinqToSql query that works very fast.

```
var list = (from o in _context.ORDERS
           join od in _context.ORDER_DETAILS on o.ID equals od.DETAIL_ID
           join p in _context.PEOPLE on o.CUSTOMER_ID equals p.ID
           select ab)
        .OrderBy(sorting)
        .Skip(skipCount)
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList();
```

How can I solve this performance issue? Or where is my mistake?

Comment: Do you have indexes in your tables? If you do you can check their health (In SQL Management Studio right click on the database, select Reports->Standard Reports->Index Physical Statistics). Maybe they got fragmented and need to be reorganized or even rebuilt. If you do not have indexes then you know what to do next.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, yea I have indexes and I'm gonna rebuild them again but even if I don't have indexes, isn't weird to not getting 25 records. And can I ask one more thing, why linqtosql one is working perfectly and other one is not.

Comment: I can't answer your question without seeing your code (both for LINQ-to-SQL and EF). Also taking only 25 records doesn't mean that you're gonna take em out quickly. You will need to first find them, which if you don't have proper indexes, could turn into a very slow operation (as you might already have discovered).

Comment: 2 questions: what is the type of `_uow.Repository<ORDERS>()`, what does the sql looks like ?

Comment: @tschmit007 it's returns List of orders. List<ORDERS> and sql query looks very complex because each table has min 20 columns and query has inner join for many to one relation and left join with one to many relation. Here is what sql looks like: http://codepaste.net/61d4if When I execute it result returns in 2 mins.

Comment: how long takes the [Limit1] view to be calculated ? what does the query plan says about missing indexes ?

Comment: Thanks for help. I appreciate. I rebuild all indexes again and my problem is fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this sql code to rebuild all indexes and my problem is fixed now.
Thanks for help.

```
USE [DATABASE_NAME]
EXEC [sp_MSforeachtable] @command1="RAISERROR('DBCC DBREINDEX(''?'') ...',10,1) WITH NOWAIT DBCC DBREINDEX('?')"
```